# Why does the text not change to 'Testinghi' like it should?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, keyevent

### Code:

It is not all of my code, but it contains the part that has the problem

```
if (options) {
  ctx.font = '18px Arial';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText('Controls (Click On Control/Key Then Press The Key You Want)', 5, 30);
  ctx.font = '18px Arial';
  ctx.fillText('Right Move:', 10, 70);
  ctx.fillText('Testing' + rightMoveControl, 120, 70);
  ctx.fillText('Left Move:', 10, 110);
  ctx.fillText('Left Arrow', 110, 110)
}
if (options) {
  //canvas.addEventListener("keydown", rightControlHandler);
  document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener("keyUp", rightControlHandler, false);

  function rightControlHandler(event) {
    /*ctx.font = '18px Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText('Testinghi', 120, 70);*/
    rightMoveControl = 'hi';
  }
}
```

### Issue:

When I press a key on the canvas, the text remains as `Testing` and does not change to `Testinghi`. The link to the full code and test is this: https://jsfiddle.net/aarav18/qj9fkzpn/

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Where is `rightMoveControl` defined?

Comment: I defined all my variables at the top of the code, even though I did not show it here because then it would be tedious to scan the whole code.

Comment: Changing the value of a variable doesn't make `ctx.fillText` happen again

Comment: All of that code is in a loop that is running repeatedly, so shouldn't it change the value the next time the loop runs?

Comment: Not that it matters but this is already a "complicated" game, what is stopping you from implementing this "smaller" change? Is it your code to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend adding the event listeners outside of `draw()`, each time you call `draw()` you create more of the same event and running the same code a bunch of times. 
https://jsfiddle.net/jr5dvmw3/2/ (check your f12 console and click the canvas)

In this case you'd need to attach your event listener to `document` and then inside of the listener do the `if(options)` check

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", rightControlHandler, false);
function rightControlHandler(e) {
  if (options) {
    rightMoveControl = 'hi';
  }
}


function draw() {
  //Updates Game
...
```

Comment: Wouldn't the essential information be that he should add the keydown/keyup event rather to the document than to the canvas (although it's ofcourse correct that it should be done outside of the draw function)